# Batch file which counts all folders and subfolders on specific directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, cmd

I'm a noob in scripting, but I need batch file, which can get special folder way from user and counts all folders and subfolders in that directory. I'm having something like that now:

```
@echo off
set /a allcount=0
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad %folder%^|find /c /v "" ') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
```

but it counts only in current folder and prints a lot of lines like "name of folder is too long". Can someone help me finalize my script?

Comment: How is defined `folder` variable (I can't see any definition, `set "folder=%~1"`)? If not defined, `%folder%` results to an empty string => `dir`  current folder

Answer (score 1):

This lists size of folders. It's from my Disk Cleanup article at MS sites.

**To see where files are taking up space**

This will list the number of files and size for folders on your drive. Each command does a subset so you can manage it better.

Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type (or copy and paste by right clicking in the Command Prompt window and choosing Paste).

Then configure the command prompt. Right click the Command Prompt's titlebar - Properties - Layout tab - and enter 1000 for Screen Buffer Size Height and 43 (or 50) for Window Size Height. Change the Color (Color tab) and Font (Font tab) if you want.

To see size of folders in Documents, excluding music, video, or pictures folders.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Personal"') do set doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"^|findstr /l /v "Pictures Music Video"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders in Music.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=4" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "My Music"') do set Doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders in Pictures.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=4" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "My Pictures"') do set Doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders in Video.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=4" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "My Video"') do set Doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders on the Desktop.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Desktop"') do set doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders the Windows folder.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%windir%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders the Program Files folder.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%ProgramFiles%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To count lines this vbscript will do it.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout

        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Line=Inp.readline
            outp.writeline Line
            Count = Count +1
        Loop
        outp.writeline Count
```

To use pipe what you want to count to the vbscript.

```
YourCommand.exe | cscript //nologo <path to vbscript>\count.vbs
```

Answer (score 0):

**The DIR command has always displayed the wrong number of subdirectories**

This is an inherent behavior of the DIR command as it always counts the `.` (Current Dir) and `..` (Ancestor Dir) as subdirectories of each directory it enumerates.

**This means that:**

- Listing non-recursively (ie list directories in the root folder)

**Dir Reports`N+2` Directories (Where `N` = the correct value)**

- Listing Recursively (ie All directories and subdirectories)

**Dir Reports`3N+2` Directories (Where `N` = the correct value)**

**IMPORTANT NOTE: While taking my Examples I have found an issue with the DIR CMD that breaks this rule.  So, I would suggest only using the "Count" method)**

**To fix the value reported:**

Either

A) Count the Directories yourself.

B) Capture the reported Value form DIR (Using a `FOR /F` Loop for instance)

**Counting is the more general solution** (It will work Recursively or non-recursively, and may be slightly faster.)

```
REM Recursive = DIR /S /B /A:D "Some path" | FIND /I /C /V ""
REM Recursive (Ignore Links)= DIR /S /B /A:D-L "Some path" | FIND /I /C /V ""
REM Non-Recursive = DIR /B /A:D "Some path" | FIND /I /C /V ""

Y:\> DIR /S /B /A:D "C:\Windows\System32\" | FIND /I /C /V ""
1498

Y:\>DIR /S /B /A:D-L "C:\Windows\System32\" | FIND /I /C /V ""
1497

Y:\> DIR /B /A:D "C:\Windows\System32\" | FIND /I /C /V ""
1
```

**However you can also use the Math Examples to find the correct value:**

Note:  There is a discrepancy in the results shown compared with the Counting Method, and I will expand Upon this below.

```
Y:\>FOR /F %A IN ('dir /s /A:D "c:\windows\system32" ^| Find "Dir(s)"') DO @( SET /a ( %~A - 2 ^) / 3 )
1496

Y:\>FOR /F %A IN ('dir /s /A:D-L "c:\windows\system32" ^| Find "Dir(s)"') DO @( SET /a %~A - 2 )
1
```

## NOTE:

When a folder, Junction, or Symlink is configured with permissions to stop anyone from traversing this folder -- Which is mostly the case of the default Windows Junctions setup to prevent the OS from looping the file structure -- DIR will not count these correctly, and we end up with 3N-2.

**I've run some testing and DIR is Definitely Adding a Single entry for the Junction folder**, (not adding the two `.` and `..` folders) which was my initial supposition, however it is then also reducing the total count by an additional 2.

It seems like this additional drop of 2 comes from DIR trying to ignore the `.` and `..` folders for the root directory on larger sets of directories, but I will need to verify if that is the case, or if the DIR CMD is always adding 1 and subtracting 4 when running across inaccessible directories.

**In any case**, The count method using Count A:D-L or Count A:D are still consistent with the total number of directories or directories and junctions (*respectively) and should be the go-to method.

Answer (score -1):

This also works

```
dir /s c:\windows\system32 | Findstr /c:"Dir(s)"
```

Comment: This does not give the right answer. In a directory with only 1 subdirectory it give the answer `5 Dir(s)  1,674,526,121,984 bytes free`

Comment: @DavidPostill  the DIR comand is notorious for counting the "`.`" (Current Directory) and "`..`" (Ancestor Directory) references when counting directories.  This issue compounds as you recurse through directories.  You always end up with a value of `N+2` folders on a non recursive DIR CMD and a value of `3N+2`for a recursive DIR CMD (where `N = The total number of sub directories to be evaluated)   So, you have two options, use one of two equations to find the actual value based on whether you used recursion, or you ca change the output to Bare, and count the dirs directly.

Comment: @DavidPostill Math eg. (recursive):  `FOR /F %A IN ('dir /s /A:D "c:\windows\system32" ^| Find "Dir(s)"') DO @(SET /a ( %~A - 2 ^) / 3 )`  Math eg (non-Recursive)  `FOR /F %A IN ('dir /A:D "c:\windows\system32" ^| Find "Dir(s)"') DO @( SET /a %~A - 2 )` General Solution eg (Counting)  `dir /S /A:D /B "c:\windows\system32" | Find /V /c ""`